# Highcharts area range series change plotting area dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I have a chart that has area range and scatters plot series. The area range is like a container for the scatters. Basically, if one of the scatter datapoint value is less than area range datapoint value the chart looks like the following image,

[Chart example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnVkE.png)

Is there any setting in highcharts to set the area range series span to the axis start? or if not guess I have to recalculate the minimum value (get from sccatter series if it is the minimum) for the area range and redraw?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi @Bonyfus Martin, You can use simple `area` series type instead of `area-range`, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/546e0uqn/

Comment: @ppotaczek I don't think I can. I have another series that plots right to left (blue series in the image). Two draw the chart like in the image I have to use an area range.

Comment: I am not sure, Could you reproduce your chart in jsfiddle? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: @ppotaczek please check this https://jsfiddle.net/bonyfus/81wz9s7o/8/

Comment: Thans for the example. I meant something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gdyejrzs/ The first series would be area and the second - arearange.

Comment: @ppotaczek this is just an example. The scatters could plot outside both areas. The you added is the same. Did you save the changes?

Comment: Yes, I did. For example the data for the first series is different. 'The scatters could plot outside both areas.' - I thought that you wanted to the first series always span to the axis start?

Comment: @ppotaczek yes that's right. I want the right side series to span to the right. So, even if I use the area series for the left one I have to use area-range for the series in the right? Does that mean I have to calculate the maximum value from scatters and update the series data for the series in the right and redraw it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `area` series instead of `arearange`, but additionally you need to exclude them in calculating axis extremes and set threshold, for example:

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Axis.prototype, 'getSeriesExtremes', function(proceed) {
        var series = this.series.slice();
        this.series = series.slice(2);

        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

        this.series = series;
    });
}(Highcharts));

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...,

    series: [{
            ...,
            threshold: -Infinity
        },
        {
            ...,
            threshold: Infinity
        },
        ...
    ]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2qbgo8c4/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.threshold

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: I am going to mark this as an answer. I have to bit of refactoring to change area-range to area series. Thank you.